# PHP if statement as variable

Tags: php

I have a variable ($statement) that will store dynamic content like the below:

```
($row[Gender] == "Female") && ($row[Grade] == "A" || $row[Grade] == "B" || $row[Grade] == "C1") && ($row[Race] == "African" || $row[Race] == "Coloured" || $row[Race] == "Indian" || $row[Race] == "White")
```

I want to then use this `$statement` in a if condition like so: `if ($statment) {do logic here...}`. This is used to match values in an array held in $row (e.g. `$row[Gender]` which has the value "Male").

Is this achievable and what's the best way to do it?

The whole method() is:

```
public function ApplyRuleset ($activeOpportunity, $step, $companyId, $projectId, $phaseId) {
    // Get global vars
    global $conn;

    // Get non declined employees for this opportunity only
    $getAllCandidates = $this->GetTalentPool ("normal", $step, $activeOpportunity[0]['oppID'], $companyId, $projectId, $phaseId);

    // Get column slices
    $columnSlices = GetSlices ($conn, $companyId, $projectId, $phaseId, 0);

    // Split ruleset into manageable parts
    $columnSets = explode (" AND ", $activeOpportunity[0]['rule']);

    echo "<pre>";

    // Check that we have all that we need
    if (is_array ($getAllCandidates) && is_array ($columnSlices) && is_array ($columnSets)) {

        // Get selected talent pool
        foreach ($getAllCandidates as $row) {
            // Format business rules
            foreach ($columnSlices as $sliceValue) {
                // Get the slices to match which facets were selected
                $qualifiedName = preg_replace ('/\s+/', "", $sliceValue['facet']);

                // Loop through column match
                foreach ($columnSets as $set) {
                    // Get olumn match
                    $ruleMatch = explode (" -> ", $set);
                    $columnName = $ruleMatch[0];
                    $options = explode (",", $ruleMatch[1]);

                    // Match rule
                    for ($i = 0; $i < count ($options); $i++) {
                        // Write conditional statement
                        $statement .= '("$row[' . $columnName . ']" == "' . $options[$i] . '"';
                        $statement .= (count ($options) > 1 && $options[$i] !== end ($options)) ? " || " : ") && (";
                    }
                }
                break;
            }

            // Finalise statement
            $editStatement = preg_replace ("/ && \($/", "", $statement);
            $editStatement = preg_replace ("/ \(/", " ", $editStatement);
            $editStatement = preg_replace ('/"\$/', "$", $editStatement);
            $finaliseStatement = preg_replace ('/\]"/', "]", $editStatement);

            // Do record match
            if ($finaliseStatement) {

                // Record matches, load into match array
                $this->rulesetMatch[] = $row;

                // Set required vars
                $_REQUEST['selected'] = (array) $row[candidateId];
                $_REQUEST['opportunityID'] = $activeOpportunity[0]['oppID'];
                $_REQUEST['step'] = $step;

                // Insert these records for round 1
                //$this->AddCandidatesToOpportunity ();
            }
        }
    }

    // Return all the rows that matched and dedupe
    return array_map ("unserialize", array_unique (array_map ("serialize", $this->rulesetMatch)));
}
```

Comment: Please format the code using four spaces

Comment: Thanks prasun, the code's edited now.

Comment: Please [don't do](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.donts) `$row[Gender]`, update your scripts to `$row['Gender']`.

Comment: Thanks @Gras, noted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the result of the if in a variable called $statement like

```
$statement = (($row[Gender] == "Female") && ($row[Grade] == "A" || $row[Grade] == "B" || $row[Grade] == "C1") && ($row[Race] == "African" || $row[Race] == "Coloured" || $row[Race] == "Indian" || $row[Race] == "White"));
```

and then you can use this result in if statement as you wish

```
if ($statement === true) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: The problem is that $statement will not always equal that. It will differ each time.

Comment: Hi Paladin, please see some part if the whole function in the edited question. So $finaliseStatement is where my problem is.

Comment: @DannyTwoTimes you are assigning the `$finaliseStatement` instead of checking if it equals the `$stmt`. Use `$stmt == $finaliseStatement`

Comment: The $columnSets array will always have different elements, hence $statement will be different each time.

Comment: @MateiMihai, I've tried that but that won't work because $stmt is not defined anywhere before that?

Comment: Yes, my bad. I was trying a whole lot of different methods to do this. I've edited the code now